# ESP32-S3 debug issue : libusb_open() failed with LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED

Tags: vscode-debugger, libusb, arduino-esp32, platformio

I just received my ESP32-S3 Wroom-1 N8R8 and I'm trying to use the debugger in VS code platformio : [with this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyJJI.png).

Here's the [platform.ini file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnFaW.png).

I'm using it on Windows10

I can build and upload the code successfully but when try to run it in debug mode I got some errors on the debug console.
The first error is : libusb_open() failed with LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED
After that I also got : Unexpected OCD_ID = 00000000

And then the debug consol just get stuck like : [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3KfJ.png)

I tried to install the driver correctly with zadig by following this : [tutorial](https://community.platformio.org/t/how-to-use-jtag-built-in-debugger-of-the-esp32-s3-in-platformio/36042) but there's still the same issue.

I also tried to lower the debug speed in the platform.ini file but it didn't work.

Can anyone please help ? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. What helped was replacing Interface 2 driver with `libusbK (v3.1.0.0)` instead of `WinUSB`

See https://community.platformio.org/t/cannot-run-builtin-debugger-on-esp32-s3-board/36384/9

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).